# Want parent MENU_LOCAL_TASK tab to show when on a child page

Tags: routes

I have a set of **local task** menu items defined in my module. This includes the following items:

- control => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
- control/jobs => MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK
- control/jobs/% => MENU_???
- control/download => MENU_LOCAL_TASK
- control/settings => MENU_LOCAL_TASK

The three menu items (jobs, download and settings), display as tabs, as I want. When someone clicks through to see a particular job, I want this to show as having the jobs tab selected.

If I add MENU_LOCAL_TASK to "control/jobs/%," the tabs show up, but I get notice errors ([because Drupal is trying to define a link to %](http://drupal.org/node/676010#comment-4041018) and can't know that).
If I don't, the specific job page does not have any tabs at the top.

Have I misunderstood anything? Can I achieve this in another way?

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want, but you need to change the url structure a bit. If I understand you correctly:

- `control/jobs`: List of all jobs, should be MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
- `control/jobs/%node` (You should have a load function for the job, if not a node than something else), should be MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
- `control/jobs/%node/view`:  MENU_DEFAULT_LOCAL_TASK (doesn't have  a callback)
- `control/jobs/%node/download`: The download page for a specific job, MENU_LOCAL_TASK
- `control/jobs/%node/settings`: The settings page for a specific job, MENU_LOCAL_TASK

You can take a look at the node and user module to get an idea on how create tabs in Drupal